# Is it possible to insert hexa values in a SQL query?

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a form that takes names (in natural language) as default argument and compare those to a table of users.

Is it possible to send those names in their hexadecimal value equivalent ? Example: for user "sam" i would send `0x730x610x6d` or `0x73616d`, but neither of them works.

Any idea ?

p.s: in my target page for this form, i defined `'charset'` parameter as `"utf8"`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes it is possible. You can do the below. You can use UNHEX() function to convert a hexstring with hex pairs to binary and HEX() to do the other way round.
HEX method used to convert each characters of the string to hexa decimal number.
UNHEX method used to convert each hexa decimal numbers to characters.
Try this :

```
INSERT INTO tbl (col) VALUES (UNHEX('4D2AFF'))
```

and

```
SELECT HEX(col) FROM tbl
```

Comment: Thank you, so by default, can i enter directly binary value of "sam", i.e 00101000 etc. ?

Comment: Your column datatype should be binary if you want to insert a binary value.